Is it okay to listen to singers who make shirk music?
Is it okay to listen to songs made by singers who often or sometimes make shirk songs but the song which i listen to doesn't have any shirk so is it okay or not?

Listening to music is haram REGADLESS made by muslim or non muslim.
There is sahih haduth in bukhari regading this

Why not quote said hadith? Im not disagreeing with you though.

Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari:
that he heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful..... bukhari 5590. Hadith ppl from this ummah will make musical instruments as halal meaning musical instruments are haram.

Perfect you have earnt an upvote, but please edit that onto the answer

Allah's warning about listening to shirk
How can you go on listening to words of shirk if Allah says:

And it has already come down to you in the Book that when you hear the verses of Allah [recited], they are denied [by them] and ridiculed; so do not sit with them until they enter into another conversation. Indeed, you would then be like them. Indeed Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers in Hell all together - (4:140)

And further, Allah the Almighty says:

And when you see those who engage in [offensive] discourse concerning Our verses, then turn away from them until they enter into another conversion. And if Satan should cause you to forget, then do not remain after the reminder with the wrongdoing people. (6:68)

In other words, if you hear other people mock of Allah and his Messenger you are required to leave the place, in case of a song turn-off the "music", "sound", "radio" etc.. It's a serious misdeed to keep doing this, because it could impact your faith.
Further, note that the majority of scholars consider music as haram. At the same time, some scholars differentiate regarding this topic, between the lyrics content, the instruments, the occasion and so on.
Does listening to shirk constitute disbelief?
On the same question, you've asked Fatwa islamweb.net #446425 (in Arabic) replayed saying: Even if listening to music with shirk text is sinful, as long as one rejects the content one can't be regarded as a disbeliever. A similar statement can be found here:

Listening to forbidden musical instruments, and listening to shirk are two separate sins, neither of which constitute disbelief.
You should repent from both, and leave them both.
Listening to the songs of people who have weak faith (iman) takes away one’s own faith bit by bit. We have to be very selective about what we let our eyes see or ears hear.

In other words, even scholars considering music as haram, consider the two above verses, more like a strong warning not a qualification of a person as a disbeliever just because he listens to shirk.
Back to the original question
To sum up: listening to music is regarded by itself as a sin by the majority of scholars. However, one can repent from it (even multiple times). Listening to music including shirk lyrics is even more sinful, but doesn't lead to disbelief.
Assuming you follow the minority view and regard music as permissible, you are allowed to listen to songs that don't include shirk, you could even listen to those including shirk lyrics, but reject their content in your heart, but it is certainly better not to do so.

It's not ok at all to listen to such singer, a singer who is commiting the greatest sin in Islam. Listen to his song is a sign of showing him love and supporting him economically despite you know that he is a great enemy of Allah SWA (by associating him with a partner).
Even if you don't love him now and you are not listing to the music he do shirk, as time goes on you will fall in love with all his music and himself.
Gradually you will find yourself singing all songs from the singer even those containing shirk words.
I strongly advise to stay away from such singer as he is already captured by the devil and devil will like used him to capture you.

@EddyJane you will not commit shirk but you're sinful. Music is prohibited
